# Windows Authentication in WCF

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, wcf, wcf-security

I am new to WCF, trying to create a .net WCF service app. i need to accept a xmldocumnet obj and username , password, do the authentication against Active directory and only allow certian role users. i cannot use IIS integrated or basic auth as some of my clinet cannot fo NTLM or Basic windows auth.

Is there a easy way in WCF to implement windows authentication and restrict role sevice?

Comment: You're saying you have clients that can't do HTTP basic authentication?

Comment: yes. that is why i need to have username and pwd to be passed

Comment: What platform are you talking to that can do HTTP but can't do basic Auth?

Comment: i have unix client and 3rd party client that can only send plain soap request response.

Comment: Basic authentication is a feature of HTTP not of windows - I'd be stunned if anyone doing HTTP cannot support basic authentication

Comment: well that may be the case, but do you guys know how to simply do auth in WCF without using IIS

Comment: Let me guess: They want to send username and password unencrypted because they also can't do that?

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9588265/understanding-wcf-windows-authentication for getting some perspective on Windows Authentication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use certificates and map the cert to a windows user in AD - then you have a construct that is standard HTTP that can be mapped to a windows account automatically which allows you to use Windows authorization.

If you will not use any form of HTTP authentication then you can send the credentials as items in the message, use SSPI to verify the username and password then look in AD for the groups and wire up your own IPrinciple which will allow you to do PrinciplePermission checks for roles. If you go tihs route (which I wouldn't recommend) then please please use SSL - otherwise your system is horribly insecure.